# Batch script with variables containing &

Tags: windows, batch-file, escaping, special-characters

I'm trying to create a batch file that executes a command (`mvn tomcat7:run`) with custom arguments based on certain arguments in my batch file:

```bat
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set args=

:loop
IF NOT "%1"=="" (
    IF "%1"=="local-mysql" (
        set args=!args! -Dds.user=user
        set args=!args! -Dds.pwd=password
        set args=!args! -Dhibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
        set args=!args! -Dds.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&charSet=UTF-8&useSSL=false
    )
    IF "%1"=="local-other-service" (
        set args=!args! -Dother.service.url=localhost:8085/other-service
    )
    SHIFT
    goto :loop
)
mvn tomcat7:run%args%
:theend
```

This doesn't work, because of the line `set args=!args! -Dds.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&charSet=UTF-8&useSSL=false`, because the `&` sign makes a new line. I've tried using escape character, but that just seems to escape once into the variable, and then the same problem occurs the next time I try to read the variable.

Can someone please help? I am a Batch noob.

Comment: Put it in quotes? set args=!args! "-Dds.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&charSet=UTF-8&useSSL=false"
    )

Comment: This includes the quotes in the args variable, which I do not desire.

Comment: Doesn't matter what you desire. You have to do it to protect any specials characters within a .bat file.  If you don't want to use quotes then you will need to escape the special characters.

Comment: This sir, it one of the many shortcomings of the batch language (which I love).  If you are a batch noob, going with a more powerful language like PowerShell might be a good plan.  It's harder to learn but doesn't have all of the work-arounds.

Answer (score 0):

The `&` symbol doesn't make a new line, it just separates commands. However inside double quotes most special characters lose their capability so just quote your `set` command

```bat
set "args=!args! -Dds.user=user"
set "args=!args! -Dds.pwd=password"
set "args=!args! -Dhibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update"
set "args=!args! -Dds.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&charSet=UTF-8&useSSL=false"
```

Comment: This sets the variable correctly, but when I attempt to execute the line `mvn tomcat7:run%args%` it separates it again. Can I quote my way out of that too?

Comment: I have no idea what mvn does to its parameters but `"tomcat7:run%args%"` probably works. Why don't just try it? Anyway just avoid the hassle and throw cmd away. Use powershell instead

Comment: Why not try it? _(you could even stick with using `!args!` instead of `%args%`)_